# Java sum from 1 to n with output showing work

Tags: java

I have a homework problem that I've almost finished, but I'm just stuck on how to output it correctly.

> Write a program that reads a positive integer n and prints the sum of all integers from 1 to n as follows:
>   1+2+…+n=n(n+1)/2
>   The output does not contain any spaces.Example of input: 5 Corresponding output: 1+2+3+4+5=15

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i <= n; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    System.out.printf("the sum of %d is %d%n", n, sum);
 }
}
```

What I have in the printf command is just a placeholder until I can figure out the correct output.

Comment: In you for loop you can write out the value of i and a + sign with it, like System.out.printf("%d+", i); But watch out for the last one, you don't need the + sign then.

Comment: Don't try and print the whole answer in a single printf statement. Print it piece by piece as you loop. You could do it in 1 printf, but what you would print is a string that you built up in the loop.

Comment: People really don't like explicit homework questions sometimes. Don't take the downvotes personally

Comment: Here's a one-liner: `System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, n + 1).peek(i -> System.out.print(i + (i == n ? "=" : "+"))).sum());` (demo: https://ideone.com/9rsomm, some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1;i <= n; i++) {
        if (i != n) {
            System.out.print(i + "+");
        } else {
            System.out.print(i + "=");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(n*(n+1)/2);
 }
```

the above will work. You must be strict to the expected output.

Comment: Int division? Will that be the right number always?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, java is left to right. It will always give the correct output. Product of n and n+1 is always even

Comment: If you multiply n times n+1, you will always get an even number (assuming n is a whole number) so you can safely divide it with two, it will always be the right number.

Comment: @RC. would you please elaborate? Do you mean this joke with 0-division?

Comment: It’s a bit difficult to read with the special case handled with if-else within the loop. I’d prefer to take the special case outside the loop like two other answers do.

Comment: @RC. it is. 0*1 is 0 which is even

Answer (score 0):

You need to print within the loop.

And you should start at 1, like the instructions say

```
for (int i = 1;i < n; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
    System.out.printf("%d+", i);
}
sum += n;
System.out.printf("%d=%d\n", n, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with the case of printing `n` and `=` separately like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Print the sum of all integers from 1 to n program");
    System.out.println("=================================================");
    System.out.print("Please enter n: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      System.out.print(i + "+");
      sum += i;
    }
    sum += n;
    System.out.print(n + "=" + sum);
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FhHK/2)

**Example output:**

```
Print the sum of all integers from 1 to n program
=================================================
Please enter n:  5
1+2+3+4+5=15
```

Comment: Why do I feel like you copy-pasted my answer?

Comment: I did not i had it as not printf till I read the question saying it required printf() I jsut chose the same vairable names as you since `sum` is what the op used...

Comment: Also there is nothing worth copying in either of our answers lmao... I think its just a common way of doing this...

Comment: I know ;) just you deleted, then we have same solution

Comment: Changed back to not using `printf()` :)